# If the budget for an employee is accounted for at the start of the year, can that employee still be made redundant?

Tags: salary, layoff

In a company, if a manager says "I am budgeting X for this employee because of this business case", is it still possible that this employee will be made redundant later on because there is no work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> is it still possible that this employee will be made redundant later

Yes, of course. The decision to lay off workers isn't bound by the budgeting process.

I'm guessing that you are either fearful of being let go and are looking for "ammunition" for your case against them. Or that it has already happened.

Unfortunately, you won't be able to use the budget to bolster your case. It simply doesn't work that way.

Comment: This year I had a very high workload. Now, against company plans, somebody is hiring a redundant person who will work on most of my workload. My manager is happy and supportive, and he has work for me. However, I am still afraid that this overlapping person will represent a business case to get rid of me.

Comment: @Monoandale Maybe the fact that you had a very high workload is why they hired an additional employee?

Comment: If my workload is 100, this person is taking 70. He/she will be dedicated to a very specific technology which was most of my workload. I asked for some help, but I could end up being the one helping...

Comment: @Monoandale You should raise these concerns with your boss. Start the conversation with something like: "*Since me and X have so much overlap, I was wondering how this will impact our workload...*" Maybe they're ramping up the projects, maybe you'll be reassigned, maybe they want a higher bus factor, it could be anything.

Answer (score 26):

Sure. A business case is just a plan and plans can go wrong. Maybe the client cancels. Prices change. Life happens.

You will need to contact a local lawyer specialized in employment law to check if it's legal to be laid of under these circumstances, but from a business point of view, an employee can become redundant at any time.